# Simplifying polygon product of erase tool results due to small gaps in erase features

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, simplify, erase

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9 erase tools to erase overlaying polygons as such:

[image: with blue circles as input features and gray polygons as erase features]

with blue circles as input features and gray polygons as erase features.

And here are my result:
[image]

there are awkward lines in the area with red marks because of the small gaps in my erase features.

Is there any robust way to get rid of these unwanted areas?

Comment: Try [Integrate](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm) on your grey features before you erase. But  back them up first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit the polygon you are using to perform the erase. There are two possible ways.

1. Run a dissolve of the grey polygon. Then manually edit and delete the vertices within the polygon boundary. Then use the new polygon as the erase polygon.
2. Run a dissolve on the grey polygon. Create a bounding box from the new dissolve. Run an erase of the dissolved
   Polygon with the newly created bounding box (envelope). You may need to run this polygon through the “multi-part to single-part” Tool.  You can then edit and delete the outlying features, the features that aren’t causing the island slivers. You can then take this final edited polygon (made up of small islands and slivers) and merge them with the original grey polygon. You can then run the erase as normal, or run this new polygon through the Aggregate tool and then erase.